# How is clearance and creepage considered in this case?

Tags: pcb-design, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage

I'm making a high voltage PCB where there are 2 grounds - one is HV ground (HV-) and the other is the microcontroller ground which is isolated. HV+ is at 100VDC. How do I consider the clearances and creepages of HV+ with respect to other ground i.e the microcontroller ground? HV+ = 100VDC wrt to HV-.

[image]

Comment: I recommend the lecture of IPC-2221 (IEC 60950-1 if you design an IT-product) for required airgap.

There is more factors to consider though. The CTI-class of your Material, the datasheet of the soldermask and your PC-supplier's guidelines should give you a solid basis.
Here under 7.2 you find electrical characteristics of one example soldermask compound
https://www.eurocircuits.com/wp-content/uploads/T325-5-IMC5009R-5009H-web.pdf

Comment: Thanks @S_G , will consider your points but what about the required spacing with respect to the other grounds was my main question

Comment: Are there any potential differences between HV-GND and µC-GND? (Are they both 0V?)

Comment: Both are different supplies all together

Comment: Yet the supplies have a common source of power, right? 
So the ground potential should be relatively equal.
Having different grounds around the same potential on the same PCB is a pain imo. Therefore I usually root for linking them with some ferrites at least, to minimize the propagation of noise and staying in control of ground drift at the same time.
Yet I recommend you draw a little sketch of what exactly you have in mind, just to make sure we talk about the same thing.

Comment: Yeah definitely link those GNDs! Otherwise OutB may not work correctly, due to GND offset, causing Q2 to switch inconsistently.
Make sure to have proper blocking capacitors and keep HV-tracks as far from your µC and related traces as your design allows.
Oh and... Please don't ask the same question multiple times on this platform.

Comment: @S_G "I usually root for linking them with some ferrites at least, to minimize the propagation of noise and staying in control of ground drift at the same time." What does staying in control of ground drift at the same time mean?

Comment: If you have separate grounds for U1 and your HF, the GND potentials may "drift" apart. 
This can e.g. be caused by electrostatic fields or whatnot. That way Q2 may see another voltage than U1 has on the output, since the reference planes aren't linked.

Comment: So if I link them using ferrite, they both can be considered as 0V ?

Comment: @winny I am still not sure how to consider the clearances for voltages which are with respect to microcontroller ground and not HV ground during the layout process.

Comment: Neither are we as you still have not defined how GND and GND_HV are related. Your question is unanswerable until you provide that.

Comment: @winny there will be 2 separate DC supplies. (one will have GND, the other as GND_HV). Do you mean I should measure it practically using a multimeter?

Comment: You should state why you are floating them in the first place and by how much they will differ. Most probably you should have only one ground, or perhaps if there are certain conditions, star ground.

Comment: The gate driver I am using is an isolated one. Since the primary-side circuit shares the same ground as the MCU, it is possible to power it from the same voltage source as the MCU. The secondary-side circuits have different grounds, however.